# Is there a "No Units" (i.e., dimensionless) unit?

Tags: units

I would like to be able to call the `Quantity` function with a null unit so that it returns the original dimensionless value. For example,

```
Quantity[3.0,"NoUnits"]
```

would return `3.0`. Is there a dimensionless unit?

Comment: If it isn't there, I assume you could just add a definition to `Quantity`. What use of that do you have in mind?

Comment: @Rojo: I run Monte Carlo simulations which output huge quantities of data with varying dimensions, so I created a data dictionary which describes each data type, including the units.  When the simulation results are loaded into Mathematica, I use the data dictionary to attach units.  However, some of the data types are dimensionless and rather than having a special "dimensionless" case for the code that calls Quantity, I'd rather have Quantity handle it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you can use `"DimensionlessUnit"` to get the desired result:

```
Quantity[3, "DimensionlessUnit"]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

(note this is the unit produced by `QuantityUnit` on a dimensionless value):

```
QuantityUnit[3]
```

> ```
> "DimensionlessUnit"
> ```

Comment: Deleting my answer, +1

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: @Rojo: I still found your answer helpful because it forced me to (finally) learn something about unprotecting symbols. I think you should keep your answer.