# Dimensionless quantities

Tags: units

I must admit that I don't think this problem is really new. However, I haven't found a post dealing exactly with this aspect of the issue.

I am doing calculation using Quantities, but I have problems dealing with dimensionless quantities. Suppose you define:

```
h = Quantity[b, "m"]
```

Now I would like to multiply `h` by a dimensionless parameter `a`, so to obtain the equivalent of the expression:

```
Quantity[a b, "m"]
```

Simply multiplying by `a` doesn't work (as you can check by trying to evaluate `QuantitymMagnitude[a h]`); this is understandable, since `a` is just an undefined symbol and as such has "unknown" units. I though, however, that multiplying by `Quantity[a,"DimensionlessUnit"]` would do the trick. Nope (same check).

The only solution I have found is to use

```
Quantity[a QuantityMagnitude[h], QuantityUnit[h]]
```

Rather involved... any idea or consideration in regard to this? Is there a profound reason I am not seeing for not supporting dimensionless symbols?

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16794/is-there-a-no-units-i-e-dimensionless-unit

Comment: You are right, that post is related (and maybe I should have mentioned it explicitly). However, the answer does not address my problem (it only deals with the output).

Comment: @GiacomoCiani I don't see a problem with `Quantity[a, "DimensionlessUnit"]*h`, since applying `QuantityMagnitude` gives `a b m`, the same as one gets with `QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[a QuantityMagnitude[h], QuantityUnit[h]]]`.  The only difference is that applying `QuantityUnit` gives `"DimensionlessUnit" "Meters"`, instead of just `"Meters"`, but that can be reduced to `1 "m"` by applying UnitConvert.  So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

(A) Create a replacement Rule:

```
rule=a_*b_Quantity:>  MapAt[#*a&,b,1]
```

and then apply this rule:

```
a*Quantity[b, "Meters"] /. rule
(* Quantity[a b, "Meters"] *)
```

or (B) live more dangerously and Unprotect Quantity.  After this you can use [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html):

```
Unprotect[Quantity];
Quantity /: Times[a : Except[_Quantity], b_Quantity] := MapAt[#*a &, b, 1]
```

and now you don't need the rule anymore.

```
(1/c) Quantity[b, "Volts"]
(* Quantity[b/c, "Volts"] *)
```

What are the risks of Unprotecting Quantity?  I am not sure, but if you start getting strange results/errors after doing this you likely know the culprit.

Comment: This works! Actually, I have a rather complicated expression and I had to modify the rule in `a_Symbol*b_Quantity:>  MapAt[#*a&,b,1]`, or it would mess up the result. I haven't figured out why yet (on simple examples your rule seem to work even if `a` is a `Quantity`).