# Unitless quantities

Tags: units

There are many cases in science where a quantity should end up unitless. Yet the units capabilities of Mathematica seem to have a problem with such situations. For example:

```
shouldBeUnitless = Quantity[1, ""]
```

[image]

```
UnitConvert[shouldBeUnitless]
```

[image]

It would seem that this should result in "DimensionlessUnit", similar to what is discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16794/is-there-a-no-units-i-e-dimensionless-unit). Am I missing something?

My application involves user input into a dynamic interface of a wide range of compound unit types, and then determining conversion factors among them. The result I am ending up with ends up throwing in this 56.62 factor whenever the units end up cancelling. Frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have confirmation from Wolfram Technical Support that this is a bug. Apparently Quantity[1,""] is being interpreted as the cryptocurrency "LiteCoin." They also claim that the intended method of representing dimensionless units is:

```
Quantity[a,1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can use "Unities" or "PureUnities". The unit "PureUnities" automatically gets turned into a number, while "Unities" needs a [`UnitConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert):

```
Quantity[1, "Unities"] //UnitConvert
Quantity[1, "PureUnities"]
```

> 1
>
> 1